# how to calculate end date using start date and duration (minutes|hours|days|months|etc) in sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I using postgres sql.I doing a query to calculate the estimated end date from start date and duration (minutes|hours|days|months|etc). The duration can be in minutes|hours| days|months .
i try to use dateif but it work if we know the start date and end date.

I expecting to get the estimated end date from start date and duration (minutes|hours|days|months|etc)

please help me thank you and have a nice day

Comment: The Postgres data type [INTERVAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) inherently has each of the units you have mentioned *(minutes|hours|days|months|etc)* built in, and a [make_interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) function. However you have not defined the *exact input* for the interval. Are you indicating a pipe (|) delimited string? Please post some exact interval definitions.  Post as text -**no images**- and as an update to your question not as a comment.

Comment: A duration should be stored in a column of type `interval`. Then you don't have to worry about units as the data type will handle that for you

Answer (score 2):

I don't have issue to calculate the date and time. I use 'interval' to get result.

Are you just want to calculate the time? Or is there another issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many way you can do.

```
do
$$
declare
duration timestamp;

begin 
    select timestamp_column + interval '65 minutes' into duration from timestamp_table;
    raise notice 'After duration time : % ', duration;
    
end;
$$;
```

This way you read out the interval from another table:

```
do
$$
declare
duration timestamp;

begin 
    select timestamp_column + make_interval(mins => ( SELECT your_support_column FROM your_support_table )  into duration from timestamp_table;
    raise notice 'After duration time : % ', duration;
    
end;
$$;
```

Support table you can add one column where you just type in the interval, so not need to change in the code.